# how do i display information associated with map markers with mouse hover using css?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to figure out how to display info. on an interactive map so that when the mouse is hovered over on location, that info comes up, goes away when the mouse is moved and when the mouse is hovered over another location that info comes up. This is a homework assignment, but I've tried everything I can think of and what I could find on the web. I'm very much a beginner and don't understand what I am missing. I need so guidance Please.

```
div#battleMap {             
    position: relative; }  

a.battleMarkers {             
    position: absolute; }         

a.battleMarkers {             
    position: absolute; }     


div > a#marker1 {           
    left: 340px;
}
div > a#marker2 {
    top: 194px;
    left: 358px;
}
div > a#marker3 {
    top: 202px;
    left: 400px;
}
div > a#marker4 {
    top: 217px;
    left: 452px;
}
div > a#marker5 {
    top: 229px;
    left: 498px;
}
div > a#marker6 {
    top: 246px;
    left: 544px;
}

a.battleMarkers {      
     display: none;                         
}
```

Here is the  Instruction for this step:
Since the map information follows the map marker in the HTML file, use the following selector: a.battleMarkers:hover + div.mapInfo. Write a style rule for this selector that sets its display property to a block.

Here is my last attempt: I've been trying for hours re-reading, searching the web, and re-working my code for hours. I don't know what to do.

```
a#marker1:hover + div#info1 {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
}
```

Here are 2 pieces of HTML for the map information:`enter code here:

```
 <div id="battleMap">
     <img src="ss_map.png" id="mapImage" alt="battle map" />
     <a id="marker1" class="battleMarkers" href="#marker1"><img src="ss_marker.png" alt="" /></a>
     <div class="mapInfo" id="info1">
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly you're very close, but misunderstanding the difference between IDs (#) and classes (.).

Essentially, an ID is used to reference a single element. In your example, there is only one map, so we could use `id="map"` to set the ID to `map` and then in our CSS we would use `#map` to reference that single element. You shouldn't use IDs if you want to reference more than one element.

Classes however, can be used to reference multiple elements. In your example, these would be the markers and the corresponding information. You could use `class="marker` to set your element to be a marker, then use `.marker` to reference all of our markers in the CSS. We can then use `class="marker-info"` to set your element to be a container for our info and use `.marker-info` to reference all info containers in the CSS.

Below is a simplified example of how we could put this into practice. Information regarding each selector can be found commented above the selector.

```css
/* Not relevent */
body {
  margin: 0;
}

/* Our example map */
.background {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  z-index: -1;
}

/* Create the marker that will always be visible */
.marker {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/* Create the information for our given marker */
.marker-info {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
/* Select the current marker (.marker) on hover (:hover), look for the adjacent sibling (+) that holds the information (.marker-info) */
.marker:hover + .marker-info {
  display: block;
}

/* Specific to the placement of our example elements */
#marker1 {
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
} 
#info1 {
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
}

#marker2 {
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}
#info2 {
  top: 75px;
  left: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="background"></div>
  
  <div id="marker1" class="marker">Example Marker</div>
  <div class="marker-info" id="info1">I'm info</div>
  
  <div id="marker2" class="marker">Example Marker 2</div>
  <div class="marker-info" id="info2">I'm more info</div>
</div>
```

Let me know if you want me to explain anything further. This is a pretty important concept when it comes to CSS, so you're going to want to fully understand how it works.

Note: When you're giving example code in StackOverflow, I would recommend providing example images to use in the HTML instead of just img.png or to just try to not use images at all. It helps to speed up the process.

Comment: No problem! If this solved your issue, feel free to mark it as an answer.